# Pulling a gradle dependency jar from maven and then running it directly?

Tags: jar, gradle

Is there a way in gradle to specify a dependency (a jar), and then run that jarfile directly within a task?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
configurations {
    tool
}

dependencies {
    tool "some:tool:1.0"
}

task runTool(type: JavaExec) {
    main = "some.tool.Main"
    classpath configurations.tool
}
```

If you don't know the main class and/or want to do the equivalent of `java -jar`, you need to employ a workaround as described in http://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-1274.

Comment: Is there no way to stream the output? I need to be able to stream output, or I'm hosed.

Comment: `JavaExec` provides `standardOutput` and `errorOutput` properties that you can set to any `OutputStream` you like. See the [documentation](http://gradle.org/releases/1.0-milestone-3/docs/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html).

Comment: So how do I call JavaExec if I don't know the path of the JAR? I'll only know the name, from where I specify it in my dependencies. I can't call the main function directly, nor do I want to.

Comment: standardOutput and errorOutput default to System.out and System.err, respectively, and I don't actually see either.

Comment: And apparently the maven-shipped version of the jar doesn't have a manifest, yet the README states it should be run as a jar. I give up.

Comment: The default standard out/err redirect works just fine (I've just verified). If you don't see anything, it probably means that the tool didn't write anything to standard out/err. Finding the main class of a Jar shouldn't be too hard with a command like `jar -tf SomeJar.jar | grep -i main`.

Comment: `JavaExec.main` is deprecated for removal in Gradle 8.0; use `JavaExec.mainClass` instead (https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec:main)